# How to write single query for column with different type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database of state in which I have data of people who are physically challenged?
State in turn has many cities

There are types of people base on leg problem, hand problem, blind, etc.

I have only one state

> people_info (cityname, type)

I need to show state data as

> State name |total people count | leg problem count| hand problem count|blind count

Same way

> city A |total people count | leg problem count| hand problem count|blind count
>
> city B |total people count | leg problem count| hand problem count|blind count

How to write single query for state and city in order to print data

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the state information comes from. Is there a state table? How do you find a city from a state, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned the RDBMS you are using, this will somewhat work on many (*but not all*) database server.

```
SELECT  cityName,
        COUNT(*) totalPeople,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'legProb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LegProbCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'handProb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HandProbCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'blindProb' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blindCount
FROM    people_info
GROUP   BY cityName
```

In `MySQL`, you can use this directly,

```
SELECT  cityName,
        COUNT(*) totalPeople,
        SUM(type = 'legProb') AS LegProbCount,
        SUM(type = 'handProb') AS HandProbCount,
        SUM(type = 'blindProb') AS blindCount
FROM    people_info
GROUP   BY cityName
```